# Does the product always exist in a monoidal category?

Tags: category-theory, definition, monoidal-categories

Certainly there are categories where the product does not in general exist. Say for instance we had a category with the 3 objects $1, A$ and $B$ where $\otimes$ is defined as $1\otimes A=A=A\otimes1, 1\otimes B=B=B\otimes1$, $A\otimes B=A$ and $1\otimes 1=1$.

As far as I can tell we have satisfied the requirements of a monoidal category without the product existing in general.

Comment: You didn't say what you want $A\otimes A$ and $B\otimes B$ to be, nor that you were only taking the identity morphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $\mathcal{C}$ be the category with three objects, ${\bf{1}},A,B$, and possessing only the identity morphisms.

Then we can define a symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C}$ by letting ${\bf{1}}\otimes A=A=A\otimes{\bf{1}}$ and ${\bf{1}}\otimes B=B=B\otimes{\bf{1}}$ as well as $A\otimes B = B\otimes A = A$ and $A\otimes A = B$ and $B\otimes B= B$, and how $\otimes$ is defined on morphisms is immediate from the fact that a functor must take the identity morphism to the identity morphism. This is a symmetric monoidal category, and it does not have all products. Indeed, since there are no morphisms between distinct objects, there cannot be a product of any two distinct objects.

Note: I simply extended your example to encode the monoidal category associated to a commutative monoid: $M=\{1,a,b\}$ with $a\cdot b=a$, $a\cdot a = b$ and $b\cdot b = b$. But you could take any commutative monoid with at least two elements and there won't be products between distinct objects.